# No puedo llamar función GetNetmask en Form

Tags: c#

Estoy haciendo unas practicas donde tengo que elaborar una aplicacion en `C#` que muestre la `IP`, el `Gateway` y las `Netmask` del equipo local.

Ya tengo el código para obtener la mascara de `subred` pero intento llamarlo desde mi formulario principal y no me aparece la función:

Código de la función:

```
public class DeviceInfo
        {
    public string GetNetmask()
    {
        string toResult = "255.255.255.255";
        foreach (NetworkInterface nic in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
        {
            if (nic.NetworkInterfaceType != NetworkInterfaceType.Loopback &&
                nic.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
            {
                var ipProperties = nic.GetIPProperties();
                foreach (var unicast in ipProperties.UnicastAddresses)
                {
                    toResult = unicast.IPv4Mask.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
        return toResult;
    }
```

Intente llamarlo de esta forma pero no me aparece la funcion:

```
string submask = DeviceInfo.**//Despues del punto segun yo deberia aparecerme el GetNetmask***//;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cambia la firma de tu función adicionando la palabra static

Así:

```
public static string GetNetmask()
{
        //aquí va tu código
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias con eso lo pude arreglar